# How can one access hidden apps on the Samsung Galaxy Tab2 7.0?

Tags: applications, samsung-galaxy-tab-2-7

There are many apps loaded on the Samsung Galaxy Tab2 7.0 that do not appear on the applications icons page.  Phase Beam 1.0 is an example.  It is not a "Samsung App".  How do we find and load these hidden apps?

Answer (score 1):

These apps are not hidden. They were not meant to be launched.
The example you mention - Phase Beam - is a live wallpaper. To use it long-press on your homescreen and select live wallpaper. 
There're many others that can't be accessed by the end user. They're meant to be used by another. Usually to provide a feature in a plugin form.

Answer (score 0):

The Minimalistic Text widget app allows you to launch any Activity (Android speak for program UI module) when you press it. Within the settings for the widget you can get to a list of all Activities in the system.

Comment: Where would I find the Minimalistic Text widget app?

Comment: On the Play store.